# How to identify if a item is newly created in a SharePoint list or moved from other list by a Workflow

Tags: workflow, list, item

May I know if it is possible to identify a item status whether is it newly created in a particular list itself or moved from other list due to a work flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to create a tracking column (like WF Item) to handle that with a default value of No.  The default value of No will be entered for each item created through the UI. If the workflow adds an item to a list, you'd set the status column to Yes.

Comment: Got your point. Alternative method to identify the items are still welcome.